# What is the difference? a or the?

Tags: grammar

He brought in the handful of books from his house.
He brought in a handful of books from his house.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

> He brought in **a** handful of books from his house.

generally would be used. An indefinite article is used because *handful* is not a specific quantity.